# JetBrains: Show local changes made in this branch

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have PhpStorm 9.0.2. And I created a new branch from master with the help of PhpStorm. Then I changed some files.

Now i can see green,blue and red marks on the left hand side if I add, change or delete a line. After I commit the changes, these marks are gone.

I like to have those (or similiar) marks for every change i made in this whole branch even after I commited. I am aware of the history-window.

But I seek something just like the marks I mentioned earlier

Answer (score 7):

Local Changes and Shelf have been moved to a separate Commit tool window on the left.

[image]

If the pane is not visible click **View -> Tool Windows -> Commit**

Or simply hit **Alt + 0**

Check official docs in: [JetBrains - whats new - version control](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#version-control)

Answer (score 3):

In the Version Control View on PHPStorm you can view :

- current change in the current branch
- history of change committed with 'log' tab
- Console tab for control command runned in your PHPStorm
- Update change when you pull on your branch

**You can launch this view with : Menu > View > Tool Window > Version Control**

For each history commit you can view which file are modified and when you click on this you can also view the specific change commited into each file.

Lot of other function Version Control with the right-Click on each commit, file or others in deal with version control PHPStorm.

*For knowledge you have this plugin for work with git :*

- git toolbox
- git flow

Comment: yes that way i may retrieve information about what commits/changes i made this branch. but there are no marks showing me where those changes are while i work on my code.

Comment: can you more explain or explain differently please because I don't understand your real necessity.

Comment: while i work on my code i want to see marks (on the left hand side of the code) what changes i made in this branch

Comment: in latest version of PHPStorm, it is moved to "Commit" instead of "Version Control"